# The correct way of using articles in the example

Tags: articles

Could you please explain how to correctly use articles in the following example?
Consider a situation in which you need to assign a task for someone:

> Implement **an**/**the** ability to [here goes a description of the
> required ability]

In my opinion, the correctness of both ways could be justified.

I assume that it's correct to use **an** because I am introducing some ability and then want to describe it.

I suppose that it's also correct to use **the** because I am talking about the specific ability and then describe why it's unique.

Could you please say which of the reasonings is correct or if both of them are wrong?

Comment: You can use the definite *(**the**)* OR the indefinite *(**a**)* article here - it doesn't really matter which. Note that ***most*** people probably wouldn't bother with either in your *exact* context, which isn't really a "sentence" anyway (it's just a "title" for a task). Looking at a genuine sentence dealing with the usage: *I'm working on implementing the ability for our users to back up their data*, I'm sure most people would go for ***the*** there. But that's just because of the word "ability" - compare *I'm working on implementing **a facility** for our users to back up their data.*

Comment: (The fact that the "preferred" article changes just because I switched from ***ability*** to ***facility*** should be enough to tell you that it's not really worth trying to "understand" what forms are idiomatic here.)